# Auctex, how to use doc-view-mode?

Tags: emacs, auctex

Newbie here. I have just installed emacs/auctex on my mac. I don't like xdvi to view the dvis, I like to use emacs' builtin pdf viewer to view pdf on its own split window on the right. It used to be so with emacs if I remember correctly, but after I installed the auctex, it seems it by default is using the xdvi. How can I switch back to use doc-view-mode to view my pdf then? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to see that AUCTeX's compilation keystrokes are producing DVI output?  Set `TeX-PDF-mode` to `t` (or just call it as a function, or use `C-c C-t C-p`).  You may also be interested in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165645/17423.

Comment: Oh, I see. Why then it by default is using evince on mac? How to change it back to doc-view? Sorry, I'm completely newbie on this

Comment: Don't worry about it—I was right there with you a year or two ago. There might be a way to customize `TeX-view-program-list` to use `find-file` on the PDF (normally given by the format string `%o`).

Comment: @SeanAllred, would you pls elaborate on the `TeX-view-program-list`, like step-1, step-2, step-3... Thanks. And beside, what's frustrating is to see the pdf file though C-x C-f, is not width fit. And I can't find any button to make it fit width...

Comment: The key you're looking for is `W`; use `C-h m` (or just `?`) from within `doc-view-mode` for a good summary of commands `;)`.  I'll draw up a good answer here shortly.

Comment: * If I ever get it to work…

Comment: @SeanAllred  Hint: the second element of an entry of `TeX-view-program-list` can be a function, see for example the `Evince` entry in `TeX-view-program-list-builtin` `:-)`

Comment: @Daniel  Is there a particular reason why you want to use `doc-view-mode`?  Why not using a full-fledged viewer?

Comment: @giordano, there is a full-fledged viewer? I have no idea, I just like the way that doc-view's pdf displayed **side by side** with the tex file.

Comment: What @giordano means is a conventional viewer such as evince or skim. There is something to be said for keeping everything in-house though using DocView (especially with `auto-revert-mode`). And I did try to get the function thing to work on my own, but having an example will be very helpful. I'll see if I can cook something up when I get home.

Comment: @SeanAllred  If your cooking experiments will fail, I'll try to check it out `;-)`

Comment: @Daniel  this question may interest you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/190882/31416

Comment: @giordano I'm sorry, I'm not using a mac. but in my emacs, docview is default now. From the commands available, mostly `xelatex` and `lualatex` are unavailable, thus pdflatex or latex are being replaced manually. Next `C-c C-c` defaults, as expected, to `docview` in the other buffer. the output after compiling with xelatex or lualatex in `docview` buffer, is satisfactory. Is this the current behavior with the latest bzr emacs?

Comment: @doed  Sorry, I don't use bzr Emacs.

Comment: @giordano okay. I don't understand.

Comment: @giordano I'm afraid what happened with my configuration,does not pertain to the question. But it's somehow related, since it affected the output of the document. Apparently, `xemacs` failed in more than two instances, resulting in the omission of my `.emacs` init file, which of course, resulting in `auctex.el` not longer being loaded. `unmigrate` also failed from `xemacs`. And so did my search, to find out, what had happened. Unfortunately `xemacs` has failed to compile due to a `lone star` error mesage, which had left me no choice but installing the ubuntu compiled version.

Comment: ... hence the assumption at first, whether some changes had been made in emacs itself. `(load "auctex.el nil t t)` was no longer in the initialization file, for there was none to start with.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

1. Customize `Tex View Program List`

   - insert a new entry, with `name` set to `Emacs` (or any other meaningful word)
   - for the associated value menu, choose `Command`, and set the value to `emacsclient %o`
   - you may need to kill and restart Emacs for this to take effect
   - you will definitely need to start an Emacs server: either start emacs as `emacs --daemon`, or add `(server-start)` to your `.emacs`.
2. Customize `TeX View Program Selection`

   - look for the entry for `output-pdf`
   - from the value menu for that entry, select `Emacs`

This works for me here on Emacs 24.4.50.1 with Auctex 2014-02-04 from Melpa.

Comment: I did as instructed, but cannot find `Emacs` in the final value menu.