# What is the best side-by-side preview method for Emacs24 AUCTeX?

Tags: emacs, auctex, windows, preview

I am new to the Emacs world. I did this transition from one of the best latex editors and despite of the complexity of Emacs at every turn, I can still see there is future in learning it on the long run. I installed windows version of GNU Emacs24 as it offers all-in-one bundle kindly authored by [Vincent Goulet](http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/).

I installed the AUCTeX according to its manual. I wrote a small tex file, but I did not figure out how to get a side-by-side preview like that of TeXStudio for example.

I found one [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LaTeXPreviewPane) called `latex-preview-pane`. It works but still do not get a PDF only bohemic script instead (see image below).

Another issue when I put the code `(latex-preview-pane-enable)` in the .emacs default.el, it throws an error, so this means I have to activate it each time from mini buffer area.

When I press <kbd>M-P</kbd> (Alt + Shift + p) it opens pdf in the default external pdf viewer I have on machine which is Foxit in this case without any problem.
So what am I missing here? How can I get a decent side-by-side preview in Emacs24?

By the way I want to compile every time with xelatex and not pdflatex is it possible to define this option in the .el file?

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Note**

- Window seven 32bit
- Texlive 2013 distribution
- Emacs 24.3.1
- AUCTeX 11.87.5

**Update** 
The latex-preview-pane worked by when I press <kbd>M-p</kbd> it does not update the preview. Other issue the right margin is partially hidden whreas too much white space on the left (see screenshot below). How to fix that?

[image]

Comment: Standard usage is an external viewer

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not the expected behavior of `latex-preview-pane`. What happens if you try to turn `docview-mode` on in the preview pane?

Comment: About your error for turning preview-pane automatically on, you could try adding that function to `LaTeX-mode-hook`.

Comment: About `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`, yes it is possible: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21200/auctex-and-xetex

Comment: And in any case, you should try to post only one question per question.

Comment: when I ran `doc-view-mode` on the preview pane -> `unable to render file. View extracted text instead (y or n)?` when chose y -> `DocView: process pdf->txt changed status to exited abnormally with code 255` any idea what's going on?

Comment: @T.Verron do you know any better side-by-side previewer?

Comment: @T.Verron this hook worked for me: `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'latex-preview-pane-mode)`

Comment: What @AndrewSwann said. For windows, there aren't many pdf viewers which respect latex workflows (in particular, not locking opened files), you should have a look at SumatraPDF. "Side by side" is then achieved by the window manager. Don't forget that emacs is a text editor, which just happens to include a (basic) viewer. For most situations, using emacs to edit the code and a full-featured pdf viewer to view the output is way more convenient.

Comment: @T.Verron, do you know any weblink for window manager to implement your suggestion of using pdf preview side-by-side? if not I will start another question for this fine, yet worthy detail.

Comment: With windows 7 and later, you can simply drag each window to one side of the screen to have it fill 50% of the screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I installed the AUCTeX according to its manual. I wrote a small tex file, but I did not figure out how to get a side-by-side preview like that of TeXStudio for example.
>
> I found one here called latex-preview-pane. It works but still do not get a PDF only bohemic script instead (see image below).

Author of latex-preview-pane here. It looks like (as T. Verron pointed out) you do not have doc-view-mode installed. On Windows Emacs installs this is sometimes the case. Here's a link to a guide for getting doc-view-mode working on Windows:

http://emacsworld.blogspot.com/2009/08/getting-docview-to-work-on-windows.html

Also, be sure to read through the latex-preview-pane Wiki page, here: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LaTeXPreviewPane

In particular, make sure that you are getting it from MELPA, not elsewhere.

Comment: you may want to update the code or hook for automatic load of the latex-preview-pane in the *wiki webpage* for the tool. the working hook is mentioned in the comments above or you may've noticed it already in github.

Comment: finally worked when I followed the instructions here: `http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DocViewMode`

Comment: Now I use DocView `sb` option -- bounding box and push the pane a little to the right to make it occupy only 1/3 of screen and leaving about 2/3 for writing latex. Besides, coming from TexStudio, I miss the magnifying loop!

Comment: Latex-preview-pane occupies half of screen by default. I liked the feature of preview on saving the `.tex` document, Thank You. Preview pane can be customized from `DocView` options, but I have to adjust it manually each time I open a LaTeX document. Is there a way to set a preferred preview adjustment at startup of Emacs? Would adjustment be more friendly had I installed XPDF pdf viewer as indicated by `http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DocViewMode`?

Comment: does latex-preview-pane-mode support forward and reverse search?

Comment: @doctorate no, not AFAICT.  I wish it used pdftools instead of docview, and I wish it didn't pollute the global namespace with names like `shell-escape-mode`.