# How to create a LaTeX setup that updates as I type?

Tags: tex-general

I was wondering if there was some program or collection of programs that could make it so I can type in LaTeX, and as soon as it sees a valid command, it updates the pdf, so I don't have to manually type in "pdflatex" or press the compile button. I am on Windows 10.

Comment: You might be interested in [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/).

Comment: Related for MacOS https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165626/live-preview-of-latex-on-osx

Comment: The `latexmk` script has a "continuous update preview" option (`-pvc`). https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/support/latexmk/latexmk.pdf

Comment: Continuos update preview is NOT a good idea for large projects. Said that, Gummi can also be configured to show automatically an updated  preview every x seconds.